# Property 'filteredOptions' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, observable, initializer

in my Angular app i have a component:

```
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
```

Following line give the error:

```
Property 'filteredOptions' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

28   filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
```

Answer (score 8):

it's because `typescript 2.7.2` included a strict class checking where all properties should be declared in constructor. So to work around that you can:

- just add a bang sign (!) like: `name!:string;`
- adding `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` to your compiler options.
- use `filteredOptions: Observable<string[]> | undefined;`
- use `filteredOptions?: Observable<string[]>`

**more details:**

- `name!:string;` : compiler trust me on this, I will guarantee that it will not be undefined (can cause unpredicted behavior)
- `"strictPropertyInitialization": false`: compiler stop your strict check everywhere please
- the last two solutions: compiler, `filteredOptions` might or might not have a value. In that case, it's your responsibility to handle the undefined value in your case (use `?.` in your HTML templates, `null` and `undefined` check...etc.)